# How to have a UIImageView inside a UIView and apply NSLayoutConstraint?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, nslayoutconstraint

I need to apply NSLayoutConstraints on a UIView with a UIImageView inside of it. I tried doing this programmatically, but I get errors that says unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

```
UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,50)];
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[self.view addSubview:containerView];
[containerView addSubview:imageView];

NSDictionary *views = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       containerView,@"contrainerview",
                       imageView, @"myimageview",
                       nil];

containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-(100)-[contrainerview(300)]->=0-|"] options:0  metrics:nil  views:views]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|[contrainerview(300)]->=0-|"] options:0  metrics:nil  views:views]];
[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-(100)-[myimageview]->=0-|"] options:0  metrics:nil  views:views]];
```

> 2015-01-09 14:36:52.476 test[543:6554] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>       Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
>
> Try this:
>
> (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
>
> (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
>   (
>       "",
>       ""
>   )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at `UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints` to catch this in the debugger.
>   The methods in the `UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging` category on `UIView` listed in `<UIKit/UIView.h>` may also be helpful.

Comment: please include the error(s) in the question

Comment: I added the error. This line caused the error: [containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-(100)-[myimageview]->=0-|"] options:0  metrics:nil  views:views]];

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
Delete all translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints properties from xib file (Open xib as a source code).

Comment: I don't use a xib file. Everything is created programmatically in my ViewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you created everything dynamically, you also need to make `imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;`

**NOTE: The views which are created programmatically `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property of `UIView` must set to `NO` for properly working of constraints.**